# Create nultiple data table relations in Mermaid

Tags: mermaid

I have some data that gives me relationships between data tables.

I can create a relationship in Mermaid but its not looking very nice (third image).

My question will be - is it possible to create such crossing/overlapping links?

Example 1:

[image: Diagram 1]

Example 2:

[image: Diagram 2]

Mermaid:

[image: Diagram 3]